# Resample one Dimension of n-dimensional numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape (1200, 500, 1) and I want to resample it to the shape (1200, 50, 1) using a mean function.

What is a good and fast way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to apply the mean to every consecutive 10 items, you can do:

`np.mean(arr.reshape(1200, 50, 10, 1), axis=2)`

to split the items into buckets of 10 by `reshape` and then apply `mean` to the third axis.